# Wordpress enqueue not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have the following code:

```
function register_scripts(){
    wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__));
    wp_register_script( 'google-maps-api', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_scripts');
```

But it is not working, can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: are you sure, add_action is called?

Comment: Philipp, thanks for the quick reply - I am basing it on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script so yes, add_action should be being called. The code snippet is from a plugin I am building.

Comment: You have registered them , but not enqueued ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in comment - You have registered them, but not enqueued...

```
function regiqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__));
    wp_register_script( 'google-maps-api', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' ); // or use just enqueue without register .. but not the other way around 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps-api' ); 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'regiqueue_scripts');
```

You see - registering the scripts just makes them available for use, but it will not enqueue until you tell it to do so. the function `wp_enqueue_xx()` - when all parameters filled CAN work without `wp_register_xx()` - but not the other way around.

Always use both as it allows more control over where and when to use the script.

Comment: Thank you Obmerk and thank you everyone else for the comments. First time using stackoverflow and have to say very impressed indeed!!

Comment: @Ian You are both welcome and welcomed. This is the best way to learn and progress - by solving other persons issues ..